# using purrr::pmap on each row of a dataframe where columns may vary

Tags: r, pmap

```
  df <- tibble::tribble(  ~sev_curve, ~curve_type,  ~trend_date, ~weight,
                          "MILO",  'HOSPITALS',   '7/1/2020',      0.4,
                          'ALSO',  'PHYSICIANSC', '7/1/2020',      0.6)

df %>% mutate(c=purrr::pmap(df, function(#how to reference columns?) {...}))
```

So I need to use purrr::map to apply a function on each row of the above dataframe. 
However, only the columns sev_curve and weight are certain to be there.
The other 2 columns may be there or may not be there and there may be other columns that could take their place, etc.

Comment: If you need to apply on each row, use `pmap`  Try `df %>% mutate(new = pmap(select(., -sev_curve, -weight), ~ length(c(...))))`  It is not clear which function you want to apply

Comment: @akrun i've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select` and remove the columns in the standard way with `-` or `one_of`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
     mutate(new = pmap_int(select(., -sev_curve, -weight), ~ n_distinct(c(...))))
```